# Subtract time from array to an array MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a data like this

```
"delivery": [{
        "status": "Not Started",
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z"
        },
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z"
        }
    }, {
        "status": "Accepted",
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z"
        },
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z"
        }
    }, {
        "status": "Ongoing",
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2020-12-21T03:52:40.087Z"
        },
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2020-12-21T03:52:40.087Z"
        }
    }, {
        "status": "Ended",
        "updatedAt": {
            "$date": "2020-12-21T03:52:40.087Z"
        },
        "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2020-12-21T04:00:40.087Z"
        }
```

I want to get the time difference from *Not Started* to *Accepted* and from *Ongoing* to *Ended*. I'm having an error **cant $subtract aarray from a array** I am expecting to get the difference between two different from the arrays.

```
db.deliveries.aggregate([
    { 
        $project: 
        { 
            "delivery.createdAt": 1,
            "delivery.updatedAt": 1
        } 
    },
    { 
        $addFields: {
            difference: {
                $divide: [{$subtract: ["$delivery.updatedAt", "$delivery.createdAt"]}, 3600000]
            }
        }       
    },
])
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "status": "Not Started",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z"
   },
   "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-12-21T03:50:33.877Z"
    }
}, {
    "status": "Accepted",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-12-21T03:51:20.915Z"
    }
},
difference: 0.013066111111111112



{
    "status": "Ongoing",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-12-21T03:52:40.087Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-12-21T03:52:40.087Z"
    }
}, {
    "status": "Ended",
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2020-12-21T03:52:40.087Z"
    },
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2020-12-21T04:00:40.087Z"
    },
 difference: 0.08 //sample computation
```

I want to calculate the difference from **Not Started**(*createdAt*) to **Accepted**(*updatedAt*). And get the difference from **Ongoing(*createdAt*) to **Ended**(*updatedAt*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could $addFields and $cond to find out the start and end time. Then compute the difference,

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XLwu_rbpGPY)for your reference.

Comment: Hi, what I mean is. from status: Not Started, calculate the time difference to status: Accepted.

Comment: Updated the solution. Would you please check if it looks good now? :)